# JavaFX: Window.sizeToScene() center at original position

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I know `Window.sizeToScene()` will resize the window to the size that its scene needs, but the position of the window does not adjust accordingly (i.e. the stationary point is top-left corner of the window). Is there any way to make the window resize itself, and keep the window's center at the same place (i.e. make the stationary point at the center of the window)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like:

```
public void resize(Window win) {
    double x = win.getX();
    double y = win.getY();
    double width = win.getWidth();
    double height = win.getHeight();

    win.sizeToScene();

    win.setX(x + ((width - win.getWidth()) / 2));
    win.setY(y + ((height - win.getHeight()) / 2));
}
```

The code above caches the position before the window is resized to the scene, then it moves the window the appropriate amount to keep the window centered in the same area. This code does not take into account where the window will be once it is moved/resized. You might want to add checks to make sure the window doesn't end up going off the screen.